# Rendering reCaptcha on python Http Requests

Tags: python, web, python-requests, recaptcha, pywebview

I am not really sure how can I use the HTTP Requests 's response to show the widget.

The problem is that when I am requesting GET in http link and it returns a html response;
but when I try to render the html part of where the widget is, the pywebview throws off error like

> A Server error occurred. Please contact the administrator.

> Or it shows the values of the html's tag not the html webview itself

Code for reference:

```
def handle_captcha(sess, request, ua):
    http_response = sess.get(request, headers=ua)
    http_show_captcha = BeautifulSoup(http_response.text, 'html.parser')
    print("hellos")
    window = webview.create_window('Captcha', http_show_captcha.find('div' , attrs={"class" : "checkpoint__wrapper content"}).text)
    webview.start()
```

The flow of this program is to access website through http request -> manually solve the captcha -> get the captcha's response -> target page

**My question here is, is there any python framework that renders HTTP response especially the reCaptcha Widget?
Or what is the best way to handle this problem?
And how can I store the session inside the webview's response, or how can I access the previous session that was generated from http request?**

Comment: @bigbounty you got my question wrong. I am not trying to bypass the captcha. I am trying to render it manually on python's gui(pywebview) so the user can solve it on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever stumbled upon this question. I have already solved this a week ago.

The solution I used is to run a custom JS script using Pywebview:

> Question #1 Is there any python framework that renders HTTP response especially the Captcha widget?

Answer: You have to do it by yourself.

> Question #2 What's the best way to handle this problem?

Answer: Fetch the widget's location then manually load it to webview. Then after that just get the payload using JS:
`window.evaluate_js("document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response').value")`

> Question #3 How can I store the session to webview response?

Answer: You can't. But maybe you can inject the session using the pywebview's API.

> Question #4 How can I access the previous session that was generated from HTTP Request.

Answer: This is almost same as the question #3. Maybe we can just fetch the session manually then store it to the pywebview's API.

Hope anyone helps this.